# In Firebase is it possible for a database change to call the front end app code

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase listener that checks for **"child_changed"** on a table called **adminNotifications**

When that child changes the code in my front end is meant to be called.
This works fine when the browser is open on the website.

If no one is on the website when the database change occurs, then the code won't be hit.

Its like the websites asleep.

Is there anyway for the code to still run when no ones on the live website?
My app is a client side app with Firebase hosting. There's no backend server.

**This is my current code that works fine when browser is open on the web address(website):**

```
 //Schedule: expires old jobs.
    let adminNotifications = new Firebase(this.environment.firebaseUrl + "/adminNotifications");  

    adminNotifications.on('child_changed', function(snapshot: any) {
       console.log("Schedular - Started");
    });
```

I'm using Angular2 with Typescript and Firebase.
The above code is based in my app.component constructor.

Comment: If nobody is on the site, who or what is changing the database?

Comment: Once per day I update a Firebase database table using zapier. When that child is changed the front end code is called. This works fine when the browser is open but not when anyone is on the website.

Comment: Yea I'm curious too if this is a feature. Basically a Websocket: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would this Websocket work for me, because I only have a front end app hosting on firebase. I dont have a backend server?

Comment: If nobody is on the web site, the above code won't be run. There is currently no way to run your code on Firebase's servers.

Comment: If I was to create a node server. whats best way for me to call my website daily from their?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it possible for node to call my angular2 app thats live at a specific route? then this can fire off a function call?